# How to dismiss keyboard when touch outside the textfield?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, uitextfield

I have this structure:

```
 ViewController
     |
  MainView  <-- Give a Tap value =1
     |
  ScrollView
     |
    View <-- give a Tag value =2
      |
     another View use to contain textFields  <-- give a tap value =3
```

The View has same width as Scrollview and MainView.

The "Another View" width is not same as View. In the "another view", I have a few textfields in it.

Problem : Touching on View or outside the textfield, the keyboard will not dismiss.

I have implement this for keyboard, but it did not work.

```
 override func toucheBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event:UiEvent?){

      if (view.tag == 1) {

            //- this refer to main view
            view.endEditing(true)

      } else {

         //- this refer to the other view.
      view.endEditing(true)

      }

--Upate:<br/>

  override func toucheBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event:UiEvent?){

      self.view.endEditing(true)  // with or without self

}
```

Comment: You are not checking the correct view tag. You are checking the main view tag

Comment: Have you set userInteractionEnabled on the view?

Comment: Do I need to put a Tag value for each of the view (Main View, View, another View) ? How to refer which one when user could touch on View and another view only as Main View is behind the view . have set up UserInteractionEnabled for the 3 views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try bellow code it hides the keyboard when user touches the view of uiviewcontroller, the code is in swift 3.0, hope it helps you.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true) //This will hide the keyboard
}
```

Or else you have to set **uitapgesturerecognizer** for that specific view, or you can make that view uicontrol and set touchupinside event,
All you have to do is call **self.view.endEditing(true)** from any of above thing.

Comment: The 1st option not working using touchesBegan. Why?  How to do the 2nd option?

Comment: @MilkBottle Add uitapgesturerecognizer to the view from where you want to hide keyboard on touching it. and add self.view.endEditing(true) to the function you set on tapgesturere